# С# WPF comboBox textChange

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать событие на изменение текста в `comboBox` пользователем?
Событие `textInput` не срабатывает, а `textChanged`, как в `textBox`, нет.

Comment: MVVM + Bindings

Comment: на крайний случай попробуйте подписаться на `PreviewTextInput`, как советует MSDN тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать привязку к свойству. В `DataContext'е` у вас должен быть объект у которого есть свойство с которым вы хотите связать свойство `Text` из `ComboBox'а`.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding Text}" IsEditable="True" />
```

**C# CODE**

```
public class Content {
    string text;
    public string Text {
        get { return text; }
        set {
            text = value;
            OnTextChanged();
        }
    }

    void OnTextChanged() {
        // Ваш код здесь
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Content();
    }
}
```